# Removing duplicate responses based on date

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I Have a Google Sheets set up for a community I run.

I have two columns, each linked to a form. One for recruited members and one for kicked members and members who leave

What I want to do is Have one more column in my sheet that shows only the people currently in my community and the problem arises when a former member who is on the kick list rejoins the community.

I believe the easiest method may be to remove the name from the kick list when a new member is added.

Alternatively, it may be possible to remove a name from the kick list if there is a more recent entry for that name on the recruited list

Here is a copy of my set up: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CqUSz_C--jidkxGF-WpNxM3cgWMndgqJnC2fEX-H0JI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ive added a copy of my set up in my post

Answer (score 0):

> I believe the easiest method may be to remove the name from the kick list when a new member is added.

this would be indeed the best method. to make things easier you could create one more column to check joined members from a certain date onwards if they are present in kick list so you could then just track down specifically those names and remove them within the kick list